# Почему функция проверки интернета на Android не работает на эмуляторе?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Есть прекрасная функция для проверки интернета на android, на реальном устройстве работает и в Genymotion работает а вот в официальных эмуляторах стабильно выдает false. Не знаю это нормально на других устройствах же будет работать? А то у меня только 1 смартфон, не начем проверить

```
 fun isOnline(): Boolean {
        val runtime = Runtime.getRuntime()
        try {
            val ipProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8")
            val exitValue = ipProcess.waitFor()
            return exitValue == 0
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return false
    }
```

Comment: Не забыли выдать разрешения `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` и `INTERNET` в манифесте?

Comment: Проверьте, чему равен `exitValue`, и попробуйте написать `throw e` вместо `e.printStackTrace()`, чтобы сразу увидеть падение в логах.